# Unable to boot Windows 7 after Grub overwrote the Windows bootsector

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

I have Windows 7 on my machine and then installed Ubuntu 12.04 using a live CD. I can see both Windows 7 and Ubuntu in the grub menu, but when I select Windows 7 it shows a black screen for about 2 seconds and the returns to the Grub menu. But if I select Ubuntu it's working fine.

This is the contents of the boot-repair log:

```
    Boot Info Script 0.61.full + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info November 20th 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 1 for (,msdos6)/boot/grub.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the boot sector of sda1 
                       and looks at sector 388911128 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       in partition 1 for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. No errors 
                       found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *        206,848   146,802,687   146,595,840   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         147,007,488   293,623,807   146,616,320   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         293,623,808   332,820,613    39,196,806   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         332,822,526 1,465,145,343 1,132,322,818   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5         461,342,720 1,465,145,343 1,003,802,624   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6         332,822,528   453,171,199   120,348,672  83 Linux
/dev/sda7         453,173,248   461,338,623     8,165,376  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        F6AE2C13AE2BCB47                       ntfs       
/dev/sda2        DC2273012272DFC6                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        1E76E43376E40D79                       ntfs       New Volume
/dev/sda5        5ED60ACDD60AA57D                       ntfs       
/dev/sda6        9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124   ext4       
/dev/sda7        52f3dd94-6be7-4a7b-a3ae-f43eb8810483   swap       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda6        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_IN
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124' {
recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-advanced-9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-recovery-9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-F6AE2C13AE2BCB47' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  F6AE2C13AE2BCB47
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F6AE2C13AE2BCB47
    fi
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda6/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=52f3dd94-6be7-4a7b-a3ae-f43eb8810483 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 162.831275940 = 174.838751232  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 163.036647797 = 175.059267584  boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic               1
 206.871749878 = 222.126850048  boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic                  1
 163.036647797 = 175.059267584  initrd.img                                     1
 163.036647797 = 175.059267584  initrd.img.old                                 1
 206.871749878 = 222.126850048  vmlinuz                                        1

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: write error: Broken pipe
cat: write error: Broken pipe

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2012-12-11__00h59 ===================
boot-repair version : 3.195~ppa28~quantal
boot-sav version : 3.195~ppa28~quantal
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa45~quantal
boot-sav-extra version : 3.195~ppa28~quantal
boot-repair is executed in installed-session (Ubuntu 12.10, quantal, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda6:The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.10 CurrentSession:linux
/dev/sda1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain

=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: UUID="F6AE2C13AE2BCB47" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="DC2273012272DFC6" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="1E76E43376E40D79" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="5ED60ACDD60AA57D" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda6: UUID="9e70fd16-b48b-4f88-adcf-e443aef83124" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda7: UUID="52f3dd94-6be7-4a7b-a3ae-f43eb8810483" TYPE="swap"


1 disks with OS, 2 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.


=================== /etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"




=================== /etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Oct 17 20:29 grub.d
total 72
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7541 Oct 14 23:06 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5488 Oct  4 15:00 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10891 Oct 14 23:06 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10258 Oct 14 23:06 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1688 Oct 11 19:40 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10976 Oct 14 23:06 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1426 Oct 14 23:06 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct 14 23:06 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Oct 14 23:06 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Oct 14 23:06 README


=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This installed-session is not in EFI-mode.
EFI in dmesg. Please report this message to yannubuntu@gmail.com
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 00000000bafe7000 0003E (v01 DELL    QA09    00000002 PTL  00000002)
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 00000000bafe6000 00042 (v01 PTL      COMBUF 00000001 PTL  00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 00000000bafe3000 00256 (v01 DELL    QA09    00000002 PTL  00000002)
SecureBoot disabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda6    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc ,   update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    .
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda2    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda2.
sda3    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda3.
sda5    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda5.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA WDC WD7500BPKT-7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      106MB   75.2GB  75.1GB  primary   ntfs            boot
2      75.3GB  150GB   75.1GB  primary   ntfs
3      150GB   170GB   20.1GB  primary   ntfs
4      170GB   750GB   580GB   extended                  lba
6      170GB   232GB   61.6GB  logical   ext4
7      232GB   236GB   4181MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
5      236GB   750GB   514GB   logical   ntfs

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:750GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA WDC WD7500BPKT-7;
1:106MB:75.2GB:75.1GB:ntfs::boot;
2:75.3GB:150GB:75.1GB:ntfs::;
3:150GB:170GB:20.1GB:ntfs::;
4:170GB:750GB:580GB:::lba;
6:170GB:232GB:61.6GB:ext4::;
7:232GB:236GB:4181MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
5:236GB:750GB:514GB:ntfs::;


=================== mount:
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/dev/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=dev)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  alarm ashmem autofs binder block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency disk dri dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fb1 fd full fuse hpet input kmsg kvm log mapper mcelog mei mem net network_latency network_throughput null oldmem port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uinput urandom v4l vga_arbiter vhost-net video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      ext4       57G  2.7G   51G   6% /
udev           devtmpfs  1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     770M  892K  769M   1% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     1.9G  260K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1      fuseblk    70G   36G   35G  51% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2      fuseblk    70G   66G  4.8G  94% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3      fuseblk    19G   87M   19G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda5      fuseblk   479G  436G   44G  92% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1dc69d0b

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      206848   146802687    73297920    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       147007488   293623807    73308160    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       293623808   332820613    19598403    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       332822526  1465145343   566161409    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       461342720  1465145343   501901312    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       332822528   453171199    60174336   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       453173248   461338623     4082688   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order



=================== Recommended repair
Recommended-Repair
This setting will reinstall the grub2 of sda6 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-7ubuntu11,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda6 into the MBR of sda
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.10] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it didn't set your boot loader correctly.

[Can't boot Ubuntu 11.10 after installing alongside Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112414/cant-boot-ubuntu-11-10-after-installing-alongside-windows-7)

http://linux.bigresource.com/Ubuntu-Installation-Cant-boot-windows-7-getting-a-black-screen-and-windows-does-not-load--0SemtNNBl.html

Answer (score 0):

Somehow Grub has overwritten your Windows boot sector. You will need to repair it in order to boot Windows again.

```
sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the boot sector of sda1 
                       and looks at sector 388911128 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       in partition 1 for (,msdos6)/boot/grub. No errors 
                       found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

You can repair in one of two ways:

1. Boot a Windows repair CD to a repair prompt and for Windows Vista/7/8 run: `bootrec /fixboot` and for Windows XP run `fixboot`
2. Recover the backup boot sector using `testdisk`. The beauty of this solution is that you can do it from Ubuntu. Reference [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bootinfoscript/index.php?title=Boot_Problems%3aBoot_Sector).

**Instructions for using `testdisk`**

First install and run `testdisk`:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
sudo testdisk
```

Then follow instructions for each screen in `testdisk`:

```
First   screen:  Select "No Log" and press enter.
Second  screen:  Select /dev/sda - the hard drive containing the Windows system partition and  choose "proceed".
Third   screen:  "intel"
Fourth  screen:  "advanced",
Fifth   screen:  Select /dev/sda1 - the Windows system partition and choose "boot"
Sixth   screen:  "BackupBS"
Seventh screen:  type "Y" to confirm
```

Please also refer to [this bug report](http://pad.lv/1079482) and click "This bug affects me" so that Grub can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the bootsector of your sda1 partition. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix